# How to set ID attribute in IIS web-sites through windows powershell command

Tags: powershell, iis

I'm trying to set the ID attribute of web-site in IIS through PowerShell script.

Tried with below command:

```
Set-ItemProperty IIS:\Sites\SetIDColumn -Name ID -Value 11
```

But this didn't help. Could any one please guide.
Refereed [Simple Configuration Changes to Web-Sites and Application Pools](http://www.iis.net/learn/manage/powershell/powershell-snap-in-making-simple-configuration-changes-to-web-sites-and-application-pools) 
[image]

Comment: After exploring more, found ID attribute is case sensitive and should be in lower case 'id'
Set-ItemProperty IIS:\Sites\SetIDColumn -Name id -Value 55
This has fixed the problem

Answer (score 0):

Outside of a ServerManager context, most EXISTING site properties are read-only.
So while you can inspect them, you can use a ServerManager object to change them.

Powershell Example:
Change site with Id 5 to Id 7, then change site "Default Web Site" to Id 99

```
Import-Module WebAdministration
$sm = Get-IISServerManager
$site = $sm.Sites | ? { $_.Id -eq 5 }
$site.Id = 7
$sm.CommitChanges()
$site = $sm.Sites | ? { $_.Name -eq "Default Web Site" }
$site.Id = 99
$sm.CommitChanges()
```